# Svelte store not firing onchange when nested components update

Tags: javascript, svelte

Let's say I want to create a multi-color picker with svelte, maybe to let the user choose a foreground color and a background color. My data model that looks like this:

```
{
  foreground: {
    r: 100,g:100,b:100
  },
  background: {
    r: 200,g:200,b:200
  }
};
```

So my app.js is

```
    import AppUI from './App.html';
import { Store } from 'svelte/store.js';

const defaultData = {
  foreground: {
    r: 100,g:100,b:100
  },
  background: {
    r: 200,g:200,b:200
  }
};

const store = new Store(defaultData);

window.store = store; // useful for debugging!

store.onchange(() => console.log('something changed'));

var app = new AppUI({
  target: document.querySelector( '#main' ),
  store
});

export default app;
```

Then I can build an `RGBSelector` component to reuse:

```
  <input type="range" min=0 max=255 step=1 bind:value=data.r/>{{data.r}}
  <input type="range" min=0 max=255 step=1 bind:value=data.g/>{{data.g}}
  <input type="range" min=0 max=255 step=1 bind:value=data.b/>{{data.b}}
```

And my `App.html` is pretty simple:

```
foreground:
<RGBSelector bind:data=$foreground/>

background:
<RGBSelector bind:data=$background/>

<script>
  import RGBSelector from './RGBSelector.html';

  export default {
    components: {
      RGBSelector
    }
  };
</script>
```

This seems to work, mostly. The two-way binding in the range inputs is working (the labels update), and the store is even being updated (verified by inspecting `store._state` in the console). So I believe the `bind` keywords in the `RGBSelector` are passing the change up to where they're declared in the `App`, which in turn is `bind`ing them to the store.

Trouble is, the `store.onchange` handler is not firing. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Full example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nonstop-hourglass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Svelte, not your app! It turns out component bindings don't play nicely with `store` — the `bind:data=$foreground` is just updating `$foreground` in your `<App>` component rather than updating `foreground` in your store.

Tracking the issue here: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1100

There isn't a great workaround sadly — until we get this fixed you would need to do something like this:

```html
foreground: <RGBSelector bind:data=foreground/>
background: <RGBSelector bind:data=background/>
text: <Textinput bind:value=text/>

<script>
  import RGBSelector from './RGBSelector.html';
  import Textinput from './Textinput.html';

  export default {
    components: {
      RGBSelector, Textinput
    },

    oncreate() {
      this.observe('foreground', foreground => {
        this.store.set({ foreground });
      });

      this.observe('background', background => {
        this.store.set({ background });
      });

      this.observe('text', text => {
        this.store.set({ text });
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```

And in your JS file, this:

```js
var app = new App({
  target: document.body,
  data: defaultData,
  store
});
```

If changes can go both ways, you'd also need to observe the store properties, taking care to prevent infinite update loops:

```js
// inside `oncreate` — would also need to do this
// for `background` and `text`
let foregroundUpdating = false;

this.observe('foreground', foreground => {
  if (foregroundUpdating) return;
  foregroundUpdating = true;
  this.store.set({ foreground });
  foregroundUpdating = false;
});

this.store.observe('foreground', foreground => {
  if (foregroundUpdating) return;
  foregroundUpdating = true;
  this.set({ foreground });
  foregroundUpdating = false;
});
```

Recreating the functionality of bindings like this is obviously a bit cumbersome, so we'll try and get this bug fixed soon.

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me :). The confusing thing about that theory, though, is that the store *is* updated when you slide the range elements, so I suspect what's going on is a bit subtler. Anyway thanks for digging into it, I'll keep an eye on the github issue.